# Split a text string with each character as an element of an array with QGIS expressions and regular expressions

Tags: qgis, expression, string, regular-expression

I want to use QGIS expressions to split up a text string to an array with each element representing one character of the input's string, like:

input: `mytext` -> ouput: `[ 'm', 'y', 't', 'e', 'x', 't' ]`

I tried regular expressions with `regexp_matches()` function, but was not able to achieve it but partially:

```
regexp_matches( ('mytext'),'(.+)(.)(.+)') -> [ 'myte', 'x', 't' ]
```

I could, of course, use the same numer of capturing group `(.)` as the input has characters. But the goal is an expression that works with any number of characters. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't think so complicated ;)

```
array_remove_all(string_to_array('mytext',''),'')
```

Result: `[ 'm', 'y', 't', 'e', 'x', 't' ]`.

For some reason `string_to_array()` adds empty stuff (`''`) to the array as first and last position, so we remove it with `array_remove_all()`

Comment: I believe the logic behind `string_to_array()` returning empy values for the first and last elements of the array, when splitting a string into individual characters using an empty string delimter, is that there is an empty string before the first character and an empty string after the last character just like there is an empty string between each character.  I consider QGIS `string_to_array()` to be more like a text "split" method/function rather than a text "to character array" method/function.